# Pause Button for AVSpeechSynthesiser

Tags: ios, mkmapview, avspeechsynthesizer

At the moment I have a map with annotations and when a user clicks on the annotation an audio plays. I wanted to add a Play/Pause button but it's not working and I'm unsure as to why.

**The AVSpeechSynthesizer**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)anView
{
//Get a reference to the annotation this view is for...
id<MKAnnotation> annSelected = anView.annotation;

//Before casting, make sure this annotation is our custom type
//(and not some other type like MKUserLocation)...
if ([annSelected isKindOfClass:[MapViewAnnotation class]])
{
    MapViewAnnotation *mva = (MapViewAnnotation *)annSelected;

    AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];

    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance =
    [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:mva.desc];
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-gb"];

    [utterance setRate:0.35];
    [synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
}
```

**The Button**

```
- (IBAction)pauseButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender 
{
[_synthesizer pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];

}
```

Right now nothing happens when I click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're initializing `_synthesizer`. Try doing `self.synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];` instead of assigning the synth to a local variable.

I noticed that `AVSpeechSynthesizer` had a hard time shutting up during the 7.0 beta, but I find it hard to believe that such an egregious bug would last this long.

NB: you should probably shouldn't recreate the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` every time an annotation is tapped.

NB2: Once you've paused, I think you have to call `continueSpeaking` to restart.

Comment: This definitely helped! I added a resume button too but now after pausing, if you click on another annotation they don't play.

Comment: I added a note about recreating the synthesizer every time, but if the pausing problem is fixed mark the question as answered.

Comment: Oh I see, how exactly do I change that? Thanks for the help nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

```
use this one for pause

- (IBAction)pausePlayButton:(id)sender
    {
        if([synthesize isSpeaking]) {
            [synthesize pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
            AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@""];
            [synthesize speakUtterance:utterance];
            [synthesize pauseSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For future help, when I clicked pause and resume the annotation worked however it wouldn't let me play another annotation as technically the first one is still running. I added a stop button with `[_synthesizer stopSpeakingAtBoundary:AVSpeechBoundaryImmediate];` to sort it out.